# AppleStore removed after the OS rollback

Tags: imac

I have really unexpected problem with my iMac.

Yesterday I've decided to create a Copy of my system, and today I've done a rollback, but suddenly I've added the appsstore to ignoring list of TimeMachine, so I'm really in deep confusion.

How I can fix this situation?

P.S. I have beta version of OS, so I can't reload it from Apple server and reinstall. Unfortunately...

Comment: Feel free to edit in some details. How you made a copy, versions of OS X , etc... If no one has a quick answer.

Comment: I've made it with time machine, and it's Yosemite beta v.

Comment: So, you have no backup of a file you want to restore and also have no installer to reinstall the system? What number version and build does `sw_vers` show when you run that command in terminal.app?

Comment: I have no terminal.app now, there are just a few apps are available in my launchpad, and the AppStore is removed too, so I even don't know where to download it again and download new OS X system.

Comment: Yes. I'm a software developer, and I've did just stupid mistake here.